# Term is undefined in AngularJS/Javascript method

Tags: angularjs

I have the following input:

```
<input type="text" name="name" ng-change="vm.myMethod(term)" ng-minlength="3" ng-model="term" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter name or username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" autofocus>
```

The method myMethod looks like this:

```
function myMetod(term) {
     if(term.length > 0) {
        return myService.findUsersByTerm(term).then(function (response) {
            ...
    }
```

It works fine exept if I have entered a name in the input and then I delete the last letter, then I get an error:

> Error: term undefined

What can I do in order to prevent this error?
Thanks a lot!

[EDIT]

This is my controller:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('project.management')
    .controller('ManagementController', ManagementController);

ManagementController.$inject = ['$scope', 'searchUserService', ...];

function ManagementController($scope, searchUserService, userService, institutionUserConnectionService) {
    $scope.vm = this; // assumes controllerAs: vm
    var vm = this;
    vm.searchUserService = searchUserService;

    vm.showUserProperties = false;
    vm.searchUsersByTerm = searchUsersByTerm;
    vm.getSelectedUserProperties = getSelectedUserProperties;

    ////////////

    function searchUsersByTerm(term) {
        vm.showUserProperties = false;
        return searchUserService.findUsersByTerm(term).then(function (response) {
            vm.searchResult = response.data;
        }).catch(function () {
            ...
        });

    }

    ...
};
```

})();

Comment: Have you use Namespace for the scope ?

Answer (score 0):

Define term as

```
$scope.term; // or this.term 
function myMetod(term) {
 if(term.length > 0) {
    return myService.findUsersByTerm(term).then(function (response) {
        ...
}
```

Comment: Are you using controller as syntax?

Comment: I added my controller above.

Comment: Try defining this.term=null; and use ng-model='vm.term'